# FirebaseUI-Android Auth UI - How to set custom background image with AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Is there any option to set a custom background image with AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()?

Or any other suggestions to set this background image?

FirebaseUI-Android version : 0.5.3

Comment: more similar details - https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/229

Comment: did you manage to find a way? I used the `.setTheme(R.style.X)`, but the changes are not reflected.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe using the `setTheme()` method is for you. From [FirebaseUI-Doku](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth#ui-customization):

in your code:

```
startActivityForResult(
AuthUI.getInstance(this).createSignInIntentBuilder()
    // ...
    .setTheme(R.style.GreenTheme)
    .build());
```

in your styles.xml:

```
<style name="GreenTheme" parent="FirebaseUI">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_green_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_green_700</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_purple_a700</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/material_green_500</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/material_lime_a700</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/material_green_a200</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/material_green_50</item>
</style>
```

Instead of putting a color as `windowBackground` simply use a drawable and you should be fine.

Comment: can i put a TextView with few paragraphs by the above answer ? or is there any another way to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to setup theme in firebaseUI:

**1)** **Java Activity** Code

```
AuthUI.getInstance(this).createSignInIntentBuilder()
// ...
.setTheme(R.style.MyTheme)
.build());
```

and in the **resources>values>styles.xml**

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="FirebaseUI">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_image</item>
</style>
```

**2)** **Java Activity** Code

```
AuthUI.getInstance(this).createSignInIntentBuilder()
// ...
.setLogo(R.drawable.my_image)
.build());
```

**PS:** We can use **setLogo** and **setTheme** together.